# How can I find the centre of a circle given a segment with compass and straight edge only

Tags: geometry, circles

I need to find the centre of a circle for which I have a segment with the bisection of the chord. I know the centre must lie on the perpendicular bisector, but I need to know how far down. I need to do this in Photoshop on a given image, so I can use compasses (arbitrary size circle in Photoshop) and straight edges (lines in Photoshop). Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just take a second cord and draw a second bisector, the center lies at the intersection of them.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If you take any two distinct cords, the center of the circle lies at the intersection of their respective bisectors.

**NB** This follows from the fact that there is a unique circle passing through three distincts points in the plane and the center of this circle must be at equal distance to all of these points.

Comment: Note that you only need a compass and a ruler to draw a cord and its bisector.

Comment: Yes, I know; but I have only the one chord, the one on the segment.

Comment: @Gary what is the problem with choosing any other point on the circle and produce a second chord?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question here : 
http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass13.shtml)
This gives an answer using compass only; as I had the "luxury" of using a "straight edge" as well, I was able to simplify slightly.